# How do Canadian chairs work

Tags: funding, canada

I know there are tiers of Canadian chairs (Tier I and II). Tier I is for full professors and Tier II is for assistant professors.

I want to know how Canadian chairs work such as how to apply for them and who are sponsors. Does a Canadian chair holder need to have an affiliation with a particular department in a Canadian university before applying for the chair? Are Canadian chair holders sponsored so that they do not need to teach regularly?

Comment: What has your research shown so far? Are your questions (in part) answered here? https://www.chairs-chaires.gc.ca/program-programme/allocation-attribution-eng.aspx

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada_Research_Chair

Comment: simply reading the program regulations will take you a long way…

Comment: From the wiki page, Canada Chair is managed by universities. But it still is not clear how to apply for it. Maybe it has to be nominated by a university?